# WordsPress Не добавляет user_meta при регистрации

Tags: php, wordpress, регистрация

На сайте есть плагин со своей системой регистрации, я хочу добавить мета данные при регистрации (телефон и дату рождения). При регистрации данные валидацию проходят, но в БД их нет. В JS файл так же добавил эти переменные. Пробовал разные варианты:

1)

```
add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_birthday', $user_birthday);
add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_phone', $user_phone);
```

2)

```
add_user_meta( $user['ID'], 'user_birthday', $user_birthday);
add_user_meta( $user['ID'], 'user_phone', $user_phone);
```

3) Через экшены personal_options_update и edit_user_profile_update, ну и 4й который в коде

Ни один из вышеперечисленных вариантов не подошёл. Вот кусок кода с методами отвечающими за регистрацию:

```
    public static function stm_lms_register_custom()
    {

    check_ajax_referer('stm_lms_register_custom', 'nonce');

    $r = array(
        'message' => '',
        'status' => 'error'
    );

    $recaptcha_passed = STM_LMS_Helpers::check_recaptcha();
    if (!$recaptcha_passed) {
        $r['message'] = esc_html__('CAPTCHA verification failed.', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');

        wp_send_json($r);
        die;
    }

    $fields = array(
        'user_login' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Login', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        'user_email' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('E-mail', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'email'
        ),
        'user_password' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Password', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        'user_password_re' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Password confirm', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        'user_birthday' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Date of Birth', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'date'
        ),
        'user_phone' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Phone', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'tel'
        ),
        'privacy_policy' => array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Privacy Policy', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
    );

    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($request_body, true);

    foreach ($fields as $field_key => $field) {
        if (empty($data[$field_key])) {
            $r['message'] = sprintf(esc_html__('%s field is required', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'), $field['label']);
            wp_send_json($r);
            die;
        } else {
            $data[$field_key] = STM_LMS_Helpers::sanitize_fields($data[$field_key], $field['type']);
            if (empty($data[$field_key])) {
                $r['message'] = sprintf(esc_html__('Please enter valid %s field', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'), $field['label']);
                wp_send_json($r);
                die;
            }
        }
    }

    extract($data);
    /**
     * @var $user_login ;
     * @var $user_email ;
     * @var $user_password ;
     * @var $user_password_re ;
     * @var $user_birthday ;
     * @var $user_phone ;
     */

    if (empty($user_phone)) {
        $r['message'] = esc_html__('Phone', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');
        wp_send_json($r);
        die;
    }

    /*If password is equal*/
    if ($user_password !== $user_password_re) {
        $r['message'] = esc_html__('Passwords do not match', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');
        wp_send_json($r);
        die;
    }

    $premoderation = STM_LMS_Options::get_option('user_premoderation', false);

    /*Now we have valid data*/
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login'    =>   $user_login,
        'user_email'    =>   $user_email,
        'user_pass'     =>   $user_password,
    );
    $user = wp_insert_user($userdata);
    add_user_meta( $user[get_current_user_id()], 'user_birthday', $user_birthday);
    add_user_meta( $user[get_current_user_id()], 'user_phone', $user_phone);

    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        $r['message'] = $user->get_error_message();
    } else {

        if ($premoderation) {

            self::_handle_premoderation_custom($user, $data, $user_email);

            $r['status'] = 'success';
            $r['message'] = esc_html__('Please follow the instructions sent to your email address.', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');

        } else {
            self::_register_user_custom($user, $data, $user_email);
            $r['status'] = 'success';
            $r['user_page'] = STM_LMS_User::user_page_url($user, true);
            $r['message'] = esc_html__('Registration completed successfully.', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');

        }

    }

    wp_send_json($r);
}

static function _handle_premoderation_custom($user, $data, $user_email)
{
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

    /*Setting link for 3 days*/
    set_transient($token, $data, 3 * 24 * 60 * 60);

    /*Delete User first and save his data to transient*/
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ms.php';

    wp_delete_user($user);
    wpmu_delete_user($user);

    $subject = sprintf(esc_html__('Activate your account on site %s', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'), get_bloginfo('name'));
    $message = sprintf(
        esc_html__(
            'Please activate your account via this link - %s',
            'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'
        ),
        STM_LMS_User::login_page_url() . '?user_token=' . $token
    );

    STM_LMS_Helpers::send_email($user_email, $subject, $message);

}

static function verify_user_custom() {
    $token = sanitize_text_field($_GET['user_token']);

    $data = get_transient($token);

    if(!empty($data)) {
        extract($data);

        /**
         * @var $user_login ;
         * @var $user_email ;
         * @var $user_password ;
         * @var $user_birthday ;
         * @var $user_phone ;
         */

        $userdata = array(
            'user_login'    =>   $user_login,
            'user_email'    =>   $user_email,
            'user_pass'     =>   $user_password,
        );
        $user = wp_insert_user($userdata);
        add_user_meta( $user[get_current_user_id()], 'user_birthday', $user_birthday);
        add_user_meta( $user[get_current_user_id()], 'user_phone', $user_phone);

        if(!is_wp_error($user)) {
            self::_register_user_custom($user, $data, $user_email);
        }
    }

    wp_redirect(STM_LMS_User::login_page_url());
}

static function _register_user_custom($user, $data, $user_email)
{
    wp_signon($data, is_ssl());

    /*If everything is right, check for Instructor application*/
    STM_LMS_Instructor::become_instructor($data, $user);

    do_action('stm_lms_user_registered', $user, $data);

    $subject = esc_html__('You successfully register on site.', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');
    $message = sprintf(
        esc_html__(
            'Now you active user on site - %s. Add information and start chatting with other users - free and fast.',
            'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'
        ), get_bloginfo('name')
    );

    STM_LMS_Helpers::send_email($user_email, $subject, $message);

    wp_new_user_notification($user);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_current_user_id`() получает текущего пользователя. После добавления пользователя у вас еще нет текущего пользователя т.к. вы не вошли в на сайт. Исправьте свой код в методе `verify_user_custom` примерно так:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_birthday', $user_birthday);
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_phone', $user_phone);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я сейчас попробовал - не работает. Так же пробовал запихнуть в основной метод stm_lms_register_custom

Comment: @pon89aa поправил, я опечатался немного

Comment: понял, но как мне получить $user_id? Добавить в массив 'ID' = $user_id или просто объявить свойство?

Comment: wp_insert_user возвращает user_id